# SQL Server: different date filter per column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to filter the first sum for year = 2014, and the second sum for year = 2015?

```
Select productName, sum(sales), sum(sales) 
From Invoices 
Where productName = ?
```

It seems super simple but the moment I add `Where year(InvDate) = 2014` I realize I'm filtering all results for that year, when I need both years per row.

Doing `Where year(InvDate) = 2014 OR year(InvDate) = 2015`  would give me 2 rows, I only want 1 row.

Result set should be

```
ProductName | sum of 2014 sales for this product | sum of 2015 sales for this product
```

EDIT: How to compute (sales_2015 - sales_2014)/sales_2014

```
SELECT  vendorpn, (sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2015 then sales else 0 end)  - sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2014 then sales else 0 end))/
                sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2015 then sales else 0 end) 
        from BG_Invoice a inner join BG_Parts b on a.material = b.material 
        where customer = 10011484 and vendorpn = 'LM321-118V'
        group by vendorpn
        having sum(sales) > 0
```

is giving me 0.055644. Calculator is giving me 0.05892350932. My `sales` column dataType is `decimal(18,2)`

EDIT2: Looks like i need to use more than 2 decimal places for division.

```
(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,8),sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2015 then sales else 0 end))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
Select productName,
       sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2014 then sales else 0 end) as sales_2014,
       sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2015 then sales else 0 end) as sales_2015
from Invoices
group by productName;
```

EDIT:

For the question in the comment:

```
Select productName,
       (sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2015 then sales else - sales end) /
        sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2014 then sales end) 
       ) as ratio
from Invoices
where year(InvDate) in (2014, 2015)
group by productName;
```

Comment: Quick question, my real goal is to compute `(sales_2015 - sales_2014)/sales_2014`. How would i get that? Posting what i tried in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

To answer at your comment you can use the virtual table using WITH and then querying it

here is the statement:

```
WITH CTE as (
Select productName,
       sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2014 then sales else 0 end) as sales_2014,
       sum(case when year(InvDate) = 2015 then sales else 0 end) as sales_2015
from Invoices
group by productName;
)
SELECT productName, ((sales_2014 - sales_2015) / sales_2014) as result
FROM CTE
```